# Topological Data Analysis Libraries for Python

Tags: python, data-analysis

In general, does anyone know of topological data analysis libraries for Python? I have used the TDA package in R, but am more comfortable with Python and would rather use that language. Additionally, I have been unsuccessful in attempting to use Python Mapper (could not get it to compile, perhaps because I use Python 3 and not Python 2). Any recommended libraries would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I found this site: https://topology-tool-kit.github.io   Says they have python bindings.

Answer (score 1):

The [GUDHI library](http://gudhi.gforge.inria.fr/) is mostly written in C++, but it comes with Python bindings, and even a few Python-only functionalities. If you have used the TDA package in R, you may have already indirectly used GUDHI, it is one of the backends used by that package.

Answer (score 0):

[Dionysus](http://www.mrzv.org/software/dionysus2/) is a library for computing persistent homology. The recommended way to use it, and the only one documented, is through its Python interface.